# button on second window doesnt change text/color

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, button

im making a Tkinter GUI that involves buttons that open more windows. The problem is that a button on the second window should change text/color (something to indicate that the LED is off/on) but it doesnt update until the window is closed and opened again.

does anyone know how to update it without closing the window?

```
def open_relais():
    relais = Toplevel()
    relais.title('first window')
    relais.geometry('800x480')
    LED = Button(relais,text='LED',command=LED1,bg='grey89',fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
    LED.pack(pady=50)
    #led knop kleur
    if ledstate == 0:
        LED.config(bg='red')
    else:
        LED.config(bg='green')
    close_button = Button(relais, text='close window', command=relais.destroy).pack()


def LED1():
        global ledstate
        if ledstate == 0:
            ledstate = 1
            bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,ledstate)
            print(ledstate)
        else:
            ledstate = 0
            bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,ledstate)
            print(ledstate)


button1=Button(menu,text='item 1 in horizontal',command=open_relais,bg='grey89',fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
button1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=23,pady=15,sticky='nsew')
```

The problem is probably that i open the second window in the 'def' function.
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to initialize `ledstate` in global scope.  Second you need to update `LED` inside `LED1()` function by passing `LED` to `LED1()`.

```py
ledstate = 0

def LED1(LED):
    global ledstate
    ledstate = 1 - ledstate
    print(ledstate)
    LED.config(bg="green" if ledstate else "red")
    bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,ledstate)

def open_relais():
    relais = Toplevel()
    relais.title('first window')
    relais.geometry('800x480')
    LED = Button(relais,text='LED',command=lambda: LED1(LED),fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
    LED.pack(pady=50)
    LED.config(bg="green" if ledstate else "red")
    Button(relais, text='close window', command=relais.destroy).pack()
```

Comment: Thx for the help, it works now

But i dont understand how exactly it works, could you explain what you changed and why it works now?

Comment: First since you declare `ledstate` global inside `LED1()` function, you need to define `ledstate` in the global scope, otherwise you will get `ledstate not found` error.  Second you only update the `LED` color once inside `open_relais()` function, if you want to change the color of `LED` whenever the button is clicked, you need to update the color of `LED` inside the button callback `LED1()`.  However, `LED` is a local variable, so it need to be passed to `LED1()`, otherwise it cannot be accessed inside `LED1()` function.